# jQuery Validation Plugin created through PHP echoes does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I have a simple PHP Codeigniter view which prints a jQuery Validation plugin call through PHP echoes, like this:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        <?php foreach ($array as $key => $value) :
            if ($value) : ?>
                <?php echo ($key == 'name') ? '"name": { ' : ''; ?>
                    .....
                <?php echo ($mandatory -> $key) ? 'required: true },' : '},' ?> 
            <?php endif; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
    }
});
```

I have used this plugin many times successfully, but now although I have seen the output (and there are no JS errors), it does not validate any input... The form is directly submitted in any case, ignoring the validator call...

The only difference I find with respect to a normal call is that the PHP echoes output inserts many tabs and spaces due to my natural code indentation when programming. Could it be the problem? In that case, how could this be performed??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No with PHP it should work, I have done it where the validation details are saved in DB and for the form JS code is generated dynamically for form. Check the view source there must be something missing.

Comment: What does the generated javascript look like?